# SpriteKit Removing sprites to redraw

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, nodes, skspritenode

Currently in my application I've been adopting a technique to remove/re-draw certain sprites.

in example, the app is a poker app. So when a call/raise/check is made, there is a chip that is placed in-front of the player with an `SKLabelNode` containing the bet,check etc.. However, removing the previous to then re-add the new is inconsistent and causes a lot of EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors. Now, I guess I could program it to nest search for that node and alter the value instead of redrawing. However, it's used in multiple occasions and will at some point rely on removing the child from it's parent.

What I'm asking is what is the best technique to achieve this without the possibility of inconsistent crashes..?

```
-(void)removePreviousChips:(NSString *)player {
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"chipLabel:%@", player];
    SKNode *node = [tableSprite childNodeWithName:string];

    [node removeFromParent];
}

-(void)updateChipStacksAndPlayerPositionsWith:(NSDictionary *)dict {

//    [tableSprite removeAllChildren];


    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        //loop through seats taken if value then draw.
        if (![[dict valueForKey:_seatNames[i]] isEqualToString:@""]) {
            [self drawAvatarWithPlayerName:[dict valueForKey:_seatNames[i]] withSeatPosition:[[seatPositions valueForKey:_seatNames[i]] CGPointValue] withChipStack:[[dict valueForKey:@"startingChips"] intValue]];
        }
    }

    if ([self displayStartGameButton]) {
        [startGameBG runAction:[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:1 duration:0.5]];
    } else {
        [startGameBG runAction:[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0 duration:0.5]];
    }
}
```

Them two examples are consistent ways to crash my app.

EDIT

for example, a better approach would be to detect whether the node is present before the requirement to remove it from it's parent and redraw it. However, something to detect it's presence is not working out for me

```
        SKNode *node = [tableSprite childNodeWithName:[dict valueForKey:_seatNames[i]]];

        if (node) {
            NSLog(@"node for %@ exists", [dict valueForKey:_seatNames[i]]);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"node for %@ doesn't exist", [dict valueForKey:_seatNames[i]]);
        }
```

Comment: Not enough code to decipher your problem,  bad access means you are trying to call a method or read a value when no object exists for it.

Comment: do you ever add the node back to the scene?  When removing your chip,  it is gone

Comment: There isn't necessarily anything wrong with the above, it's just that it's holding a tendency to crash when a sprite is redrawn. i.e, sometimes the remove will call after the redraw of the new and cause a crash. The nodes are added back into the scene yes, and a redrawn using most of the same instances as the removed.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I'm more or less asking for the best practise to uphold when doing such a thing?

Comment: If I were doing this, I would just have 1 chip premade as a member of the class, that gets passed to each player when needed.  If no player has the chips, then I would just remove it from the player.  This way you are not constantly allocing a new chip when needed.